# create/deploy master page and page layouts using spfx

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, page-layout, sharepoint-framework

how to create and deploy Master Page and page layouts using the SharePoint Framework?

SharePoint Framework is all about related to creating client side webparts only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you cannot create master pages and page layouts using SharePoint Framework.

In SPFX, there is nothing like Master Pages and Page Layouts. 
You can try SPFX extensions for Page Styling. Here are a few links for your help:

1. [Link 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
2. [Link 2](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions)

Hope the above will help you.
Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, we would be using the same approach as we have in SP2013 to create master pages and page layouts using the design manager?

Comment: Yes, you can do it but only for SharePoint 2013 Classic pages but not for SharePoint Framework. And request you to please upvote and mark my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: sure and how can i add SharePoint framework client side webpart to the page layout?

Comment: SPFX web has to be add as an app in app catalog and can be added to the required site as a web part.

Comment: it means we need to add the webparts manually on the master page and on page layouts?