# Classic or Modern Site for Website Development - spfx unable to be used for master page

Tags: master-page, page-layout, design-manager, responsive, modern-team-site

I am new to Sharepoint development, and am trying to build a custom responsive website through Sharepoint

Understand that there are 2 different kinds of sites: classic and modern.

For classic, we can use master pages, page layout and design manager.

For modern, we have the new Sharepoint Framework, spfx. However, I am only able to find information to build a webpart based on spfx. Based on [link1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233250/create-deploy-master-page-and-page-layouts-using-spfx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802013/can-we-customize-mater-page-and-layouts-with-spfx), master page cannot be built with spfx.

Does it then mean it will be better for me to stick with the classic site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of opinion and requirements of course, but at it's current state i would say the modern pages are more than ready to be used in production sites. You can customize them as you've discovered, with SharePoint Framework, and you can apply a theme as a part of a site design.

The classic look will be a thing of the past at some point, so my clear recommendation is to go with the modern layout.

You are more constrained with the modern layout, but it's honestly a really good thing.